# Spring Integration Capturing JMSTemplate Time To Live Time Outs

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have JMS Messages that are sent to an IBM MQ Queue, if the remote Client (I have not control over the remote client) does not consume the message in a given time (Say 1 minute) The message should Expire (I have the Expire part working, "MQ deletes the message" using setExplicitQosEnabled and setTimeToLive on the JMSTemplate) and the message sender (My SI Code) should be notified that the message was not delivered to the remote client so that the expired message can be reroute to another Queue.

I am not sure how to implement this pattern using Spring Integration especially as the messages are sent asynchronously and only correlated upon return (MessageID -> CorrelationID).

I thought I could have some form of:

1) ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter, but I need the payload so I can resend the message and I am not sure how to implement this (How to call back from MQ to JMSTemplate or Route to another Queue on Time out, and have a secondary route listening to that queue and rerouting)

2) WireTap, but I think this would mean blocking threads on the sender (Request/Response model) with timer that watches for the msg to be removed by the remote client. Again I am not sure how to implement this.

Any help with how best to implement the above greatly appreciated.

**Progress report:**
I have tried to Query MQ by using the method   `JMSTemplate.receiveSelected(destination, messageSelector);` that Artem Bilan suggested. The plan was to manually find messages that have not been consumed by the Client in the given time. (The Provider would have to track all messages and attempt to retrieve each message using its messageID once the timer had expired, instead of using TimeToLive message expiry) This solution places the onus on the Provider to track and time every message sent and attempt to retrieve each message (most which should not be available) making it inefficient but a workable solution. Unfortunately IBM MQ does not like the it when I call: `JMSTemplate.receiveSelected(destination, messageSelector);` I get the following error:

`org.springframework.jms.InvalidSelectorException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue ‘MY.TEST.IN'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidSelectorException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'MY.TEST.IN'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2459' ('MQRC_SELECTOR_SYNTAX_ERROR').`

however using `JMSTemplate.receive(destination);` with the same destination does read a message off the queue.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer the Spring specific configuration, but in IBM MQ you can set reporting options on the original message you send which will cause the destination queue manager to send back a report message when the original message expires, you can flag it to include the original message as well.

Comment: Hi Josh, these reporting options, is this something I can set on the JMS Message itself (in the Header maybe?) or does it need to be done on the Queue Manager (Unfortunately this is looked after by another department so not that easy to have changed!) and how are the reports returned to my application? (Via the JMS Session maybe?)

Comment: This is documented in the IBM MQ v8 KC page "[JMS report messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rmj_reports.html)".  You would set the `JMS_IBM_Report_Expiration` property to `MQRO_EXPIRATION_WITH_FULL_DATA`.  The receiving queue manager would send back a report message which includes the original message content when the message expires to the ReplyToQueue and ReplyToQmgr specified in the MQMD.

Comment: This would assume the receiving queue manager knows how to route back to "ReplyToQmgr" and that a exit is not in place that would remove the reporting options (it is not very common to have such an exit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code causes IBM MQ V8 to automagicaly reroute an expired message to the JMSReplyTo queue, (Thanks to JoshMc for his suggestion in the comments above)

```
jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(3000l);
jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
jmsTemplate.setPriority(Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY);
jmsTemplate.send(destinationName, session -> {
    TextMessage toSend = session.createTextMessage(message)
    toSend.setIntProperty("JMS_IBM_Report_Expiration", 14680064);
    Queue queue = session.createQueue(“TEST.EXPIRE.REPORT”);
    toSend.setJMSReplyTo(queue);

    return toSend;
});
```

The JMS_IBM_Report_Expiration value of 14680064 I found here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/constant-values.html#com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.ApiJmsConstants.MQRO_EXPIRATION_WITH_FULL_DATA

I need to find this JAR and add it to my project, however MQ Removes the expired message and deposits it on my specified reply to queue.

Answer (score 0):

What you explain is fully sufficient for the DLQ scenario: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q020730_.htm.

What you need is to configure DLQ for your original queue and after expiration messages will be moved to the DLQ.

You really can configure a listener in your application to this DLQ and perform an appropriate logic via Spring Integration already: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-message-driven-channel-adapter

Comment: in IBM MQ expired messages do not go to the DLQ, they "expire" and or no longer present on the queue.

Comment: Hi Artem, unfortunately as Josh points out, the message just disappears. The DLQ works fine for messages that are not delivered at all, but in my scenario the message is delivered but not read in the required time frame. I was wondering if maybe I could retrieved expired messages from the JMS Session at all? Maybe the Sent Message has some sort of state once Delivered and Read vs Delivered and Expired?

Comment: If the message is read from the queue, it disappears from the queue as well. You can try to use `JmsTemplate.browse()` to peek into queue without retrieving

Comment: Hi Artem, unfortunately that would mean I would need a watcher that constantly monitored the queue and would need to keep track of all messages that enter the queue to figure out which are still there. Currently when the message expires MQ removes the message so it is not available to browse. 1st prize would be to get a call back when the message is not delivered, but how? Another option I am playing with is JMSXDeliveryCount, it goes from zero to 1 when the message is read (On the receiving instance), but the reference the sender holds is not incremented.

Comment: Well, that's not good to say, but looks like IBM MQ doesn't fit your use-case. And sorry I forgot to mention that for the browse approach you should not use expire and implement removal logic by yourself, not relying on MQ any more

Comment: Hi Artem, I think you re right re letting MQ remove the message, So where would one implement the message removal in Spring JMSTemplate? `jmsTemplate.execute(destinationName,  (session, producer) ->{

            TextMessage toSend = session.createTextMessage(message);
            producer.send(toSend);
            //add a listener or store Message so it can be removed at a specific time?

            return toSend;
        });`

Comment: After browsing you ca get a message `id` and then you can use like `receiveSelected("JMSCorrelationID ='"+id+"'")`.

Comment: Yeah. That's great that you understand all the JMS principles. But unfortunately it isn't DB, so no choice rather than hack that way. Another option would be a notification from the consumer app about message receiving. If no notification during some time, consider message as expired